# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, jodatime

I am getting an SQL exception while am passing `DateTime` to my Insert query via Hibernate.

Please find my Java code where am trying to pass `DateTime`:

```
claimGroupingHistory.setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
claimGroupMappingRepository.insertClaimGroupingHistory(claimGroupingHistory.getDealerCode(),
        claimGroupingHistory.getCreatedAt(),
        claimGroupingHistory.getCreatedBy());
```

I am getting `DateTime` in the format when I sysout: `2019-01-10T13:59:36.700+05:30`.

Please find my insert query

Please find my exception am getting

```
2019-01-10 13:59:36,754 [http-9292-1] ERROR   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: 146 - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x16org.joda.time.DateTime\xB8<xdj[\xDD\xF9\x02\x00\x00xr\x00\x1Forg.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime\xFF\xFF\x' for column 'created_at' at row 1
2019-01-10 13:59:36,774 [http-9292-1] ERROR         com.cat.pscs.api.controller.BaseController:  57 - Data Integrity Violation Exception : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help `hibernate` persist `DateTime` to a database, you should use `joda-time-hibernate` rather than `joda-time` in the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Modify your entity:

```
@Column
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createdAt;
```

Note that version 1.4 is for Hibernate 3.6. So update `joda-time-hibernate` when you use a higher level hibernate.

***Alternatives:***

Declare an extra dependency in the `pom.xml`, it can support the persistence for `joda-time`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.extended</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Modify the entity:

```
@Column
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private DateTime createdAt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following annotation in your entity class in order to persist joda DateTime:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createdAt;
```

Also make sure that your have jadira-usertype-core.jar in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```